# Cairo Docks Overlaps All Windows

Tags: lubuntu, cairo-dock, cairo

[image: Cairo-dock Overlaps]

help anyone, cairo-docks just overlaps all windows and cover it with transparant border

Current distro Lubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im already solve it with enable compositing

`sudo apt install xcompmgr -y`
and run it with `xcompmgr -n &`

you can also autostart it by add it into ${HOME}/.config/lxsession/autostart

`nano /${HOME}/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`

and add the command

`@xcompmgr -n &`

Comment: For this to be a useful answer so other folks can find help from it, please tell us what steps you did to enable compositing, and maybe even add weblinks to pages which provide background and/or options. I hope my answer, although it didn't do what you wanted, provides an example of how to structure an answer.

Comment: done :D, hope it can helps the community, sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

As per [man cairo-dock](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cairo-dock.1.html) edit Cairo Dock's launcher to remove the -a option (to turn off keep-above), and add -s option (which turns off sticky behavior). Click on that *man* link for more options.

Comment: umm i think im not ask a proper question, im supposed to say my dock is covering other windows with a transparant border like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_RWc4U6-vY&t=4s